# AlpineJS, my header dropdown works for large screens but not for the mobile responsive menu?

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

I'm trying to use AlpineJS to close and open dropdowns for my header NAV. The header is responsive for large and mobile screens. I'm able to get the header dropdown to work on large screens, but for some reason it does not work on mobile screens? I'm basically using the exact same syntax and tried many others. Still no luck. Maybe this is a bug? Could someone let me know if I'm in the wrong here?

[Here is my CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-rain-ljux4?file=/index.html) I'm using TailwindCSS and left everything in there for the most part to replicate my problem.

Please note my mobile menu button is hidden on large screens, its on `line 42`

The dropdown `<div>` that it's meant to open is on line `327`

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is working now , there was a problems with your buttons they were hidden behind other divs and not accessible in reality . i have even erased one button

https://codesandbox.io/s/async-field-os411?file=/index.html:0-16377&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675